# Year drop down value not getting in fire fox browser

Tags: angularjs, firefox, datepicker

Am using one library for date selection,it is working fine before applying the maximum year condition in both the browsers.
when applying the condition it is not working in firefox.
Here is the code :

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
                  <span for="">DOB</span>
                  <ng-combo-date-picker ng-placeholder="Year,Month,Date" ng-max-date="{{ maxYear + '-12-31' }}" ng-attrs-date='{"class": "form-control"}' ng-attrs-month='{"class": "form-control"}' ng-attrs-year='{"class": "form-control"}' ng-model="dateOfBirth" required></ng-combo-date-picker>
                </div>
```

And Plunker as well:

https://embed.plnkr.co/bgWKBb6MfoCm7sPFPzYU/

and when passing the normal date it is working fine like:"2001-12-31"

and my js code:

```
var skipYears  =16,minYear = 1900;
    var maxYear = new Date().getFullYear() -skipYears;

    $scope.minDate = new Date(minYear, 0, 1);
    $scope.maxDate = new Date(maxYear, 0, 0);
```